# Why my CollapsibleTree code is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js

I was trying to mimic the CollapsibleTree Search code posted here by Patrick Brockmann (http://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23) , and created a few files, the index html file and the other js files on my machine (in one folder) and it didn't work / or show me anything. I tried to keep the scripts with the online hyperlinks and didn't work too.

Please, what went wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.found {
  fill: #ff4136;
  stroke: #ff4136;
}

.search {
  float: left;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  width: 30%;
}

ul.select2-results {
 max-height: 100px;
}

.select2-container,
.select2-drop,
.select2-search,
.select2-search input {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

#block_container {
  display: inline;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="javascripts/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/select2.min.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/select2.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css"></link> -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script> -->

<div id="block_container">
   <div id="searchName"></div>
</div>

<script>

//===============================================
function select2DataCollectName(d) {
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
    select2Data.push(d.name);
}

//===============================================
function searchTree(d) {
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(searchTree);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(searchTree);
    var searchFieldValue = eval(searchField);
    if (searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match(searchText)) {
            // Walk parent chain
            var ancestors = [];
            var parent = d;
            while (typeof(parent) !== "undefined") {
                ancestors.push(parent);
        //console.log(parent);
                parent.class = "found";
                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        //console.log(ancestors);
    }
}

//===============================================
function clearAll(d) {
    d.class = "";
    if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(clearAll);
    else if (d._children)
        d._children.forEach(clearAll);
}

//===============================================
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

//===============================================
function collapseAllNotFound(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        if (d.class !== "found") {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
            d.children = null;
    } else
            d.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
    }
}

//===============================================
function expandAll(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d.children.forEach(expandAll);
        d._children = null;
    } else if (d.children)
        d.children.forEach(expandAll);
}

//===============================================
// Toggle children on click.
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  clearAll(root);
  update(d);
  $("#searchName").select2("val", "");
}

//===============================================
$("#searchName").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
    clearAll(root);
    expandAll(root);
    update(root);

    searchField = "d.name";
    searchText = e.object.text;
    searchTree(root);
    root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
    update(root);
})

//===============================================
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  select2Data = [];
  select2DataCollectName(root);
  select2DataObject = [];
  select2Data.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a > b) return 1; // sort
            if (a < b) return -1;
            return 0;
        })
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
        }) // remove duplicate items
        .filter(function(item, i, ar) {
            select2DataObject.push({
                "id": i,
                "text": item
            });
        });
  $("#searchName").select2({
        data: select2DataObject,
        containerCssClass: "search"
  });

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", toggle);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            } else if (d._children) {
                return "lightsteelblue";
            } else {
                return "#fff";
            }
        })
        .style("stroke", function(d) {
            if (d.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136"; //red
            }
        });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
            if (d.target.class === "found") {
                return "#ff4136";
            }
        });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a snippet and see. Well it seems to be working, just make sure your data (flare.json) is coming from the right place. Try from https://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/raw/0f22818096428b12ea23/fbfdb921528e8fd74b2de4231423d3a817bea0a4/flare.json or use hardcoded like I did because json isn't working here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .found {
        fill: #ff4136;
        stroke: #ff4136;
    }

    .search {
        float: left;
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        width: 30%;
    }

    ul.select2-results {
        max-height: 100px;
    }

    .select2-container,
    .select2-drop,
    .select2-search,
    .select2-search input {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    #block_container {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css">
    </link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

    <div id="block_container">
        <div id="searchName"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        //===============================================
        function select2DataCollectName(d) {
            if (d.children)
                d.children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
            else if (d._children)
                d._children.forEach(select2DataCollectName);
            select2Data.push(d.name);
        }

        //===============================================
        function searchTree(d) {
            if (d.children)
                d.children.forEach(searchTree);
            else if (d._children)
                d._children.forEach(searchTree);
            var searchFieldValue = eval(searchField);
            if (searchFieldValue && searchFieldValue.match(searchText)) {
                // Walk parent chain
                var ancestors = [];
                var parent = d;
                while (typeof (parent) !== "undefined") {
                    ancestors.push(parent);
                    //console.log(parent);
                    parent.class = "found";
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                //console.log(ancestors);
            }
        }

        //===============================================
        function clearAll(d) {
            d.class = "";
            if (d.children)
                d.children.forEach(clearAll);
            else if (d._children)
                d._children.forEach(clearAll);
        }

        //===============================================
        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        //===============================================
        function collapseAllNotFound(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                if (d.class !== "found") {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
                    d.children = null;
                } else
                    d.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
            }
        }

        //===============================================
        function expandAll(d) {
            if (d._children) {
                d.children = d._children;
                d.children.forEach(expandAll);
                d._children = null;
            } else if (d.children)
                d.children.forEach(expandAll);
        }

        //===============================================
        // Toggle children on click.
        function toggle(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            clearAll(root);
            update(d);
            $("#searchName").select2("val", "");
        }

        //===============================================
        $("#searchName").on("select2-selecting", function (e) {
            clearAll(root);
            expandAll(root);
            update(root);

            searchField = "d.name";
            searchText = e.object.text;
            searchTree(root);
            root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
            update(root);
        })

        //===============================================
        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 120,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 120
        },
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function (d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        (function (flare) {
            root = flare;
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            select2Data = [];
            select2DataCollectName(root);
            select2DataObject = [];
            select2Data.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a > b) return 1; // sort
                if (a < b) return -1;
                return 0;
            })
                .filter(function (item, i, ar) {
                    return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
                }) // remove duplicate items
                .filter(function (item, i, ar) {
                    select2DataObject.push({
                        "id": i,
                        "text": item
                    });
                });
            $("#searchName").select2({
                data: select2DataObject,
                containerCssClass: "search"
            });

            function collapse(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }

            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);
        })({
            "name": "flare",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "analytics",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "cluster",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938 },
                                { "name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812 },
                                { "name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714 },
                                { "name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "graph",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534 },
                                { "name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731 },
                                { "name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840 },
                                { "name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914 },
                                { "name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "optimization",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074 }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "animate",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "Easing", "size": 17010 },
                        { "name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842 },
                        {
                            "name": "interpolate",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983 },
                                { "name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047 },
                                { "name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375 },
                                { "name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746 },
                                { "name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202 },
                                { "name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382 },
                                { "name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629 },
                                { "name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675 },
                                { "name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041 },
                        { "name": "Parallel", "size": 5176 },
                        { "name": "Pause", "size": 449 },
                        { "name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593 },
                        { "name": "Sequence", "size": 5534 },
                        { "name": "Transition", "size": 9201 },
                        { "name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975 },
                        { "name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116 },
                        { "name": "Tween", "size": 6006 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "data",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "converters",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "Converters", "size": 721 },
                                { "name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294 },
                                { "name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800 },
                                { "name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314 },
                                { "name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "DataField", "size": 1759 },
                        { "name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165 },
                        { "name": "DataSet", "size": 586 },
                        { "name": "DataSource", "size": 3331 },
                        { "name": "DataTable", "size": 772 },
                        { "name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "display",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833 },
                        { "name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732 },
                        { "name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623 },
                        { "name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "flex",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "physics",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "DragForce", "size": 1082 },
                        { "name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336 },
                        { "name": "IForce", "size": 319 },
                        { "name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498 },
                        { "name": "Particle", "size": 2822 },
                        { "name": "Simulation", "size": 9983 },
                        { "name": "Spring", "size": 2213 },
                        { "name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "query",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616 },
                        { "name": "And", "size": 1027 },
                        { "name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891 },
                        { "name": "Average", "size": 891 },
                        { "name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893 },
                        { "name": "Comparison", "size": 5103 },
                        { "name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677 },
                        { "name": "Count", "size": 781 },
                        { "name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141 },
                        { "name": "Distinct", "size": 933 },
                        { "name": "Expression", "size": 5130 },
                        { "name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617 },
                        { "name": "Fn", "size": 3240 },
                        { "name": "If", "size": 2732 },
                        { "name": "IsA", "size": 2039 },
                        { "name": "Literal", "size": 1214 },
                        { "name": "Match", "size": 3748 },
                        { "name": "Maximum", "size": 843 },
                        {
                            "name": "methods",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "add", "size": 593 },
                                { "name": "and", "size": 330 },
                                { "name": "average", "size": 287 },
                                { "name": "count", "size": 277 },
                                { "name": "distinct", "size": 292 },
                                { "name": "div", "size": 595 },
                                { "name": "eq", "size": 594 },
                                { "name": "fn", "size": 460 },
                                { "name": "gt", "size": 603 },
                                { "name": "gte", "size": 625 },
                                { "name": "iff", "size": 748 },
                                { "name": "isa", "size": 461 },
                                { "name": "lt", "size": 597 },
                                { "name": "lte", "size": 619 },
                                { "name": "max", "size": 283 },
                                { "name": "min", "size": 283 },
                                { "name": "mod", "size": 591 },
                                { "name": "mul", "size": 603 },
                                { "name": "neq", "size": 599 },
                                { "name": "not", "size": 386 },
                                { "name": "or", "size": 323 },
                                { "name": "orderby", "size": 307 },
                                { "name": "range", "size": 772 },
                                { "name": "select", "size": 296 },
                                { "name": "stddev", "size": 363 },
                                { "name": "sub", "size": 600 },
                                { "name": "sum", "size": 280 },
                                { "name": "update", "size": 307 },
                                { "name": "variance", "size": 335 },
                                { "name": "where", "size": 299 },
                                { "name": "xor", "size": 354 },
                                { "name": "_", "size": 264 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "Minimum", "size": 843 },
                        { "name": "Not", "size": 1554 },
                        { "name": "Or", "size": 970 },
                        { "name": "Query", "size": 13896 },
                        { "name": "Range", "size": 1594 },
                        { "name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130 },
                        { "name": "Sum", "size": 791 },
                        { "name": "Variable", "size": 1124 },
                        { "name": "Variance", "size": 1876 },
                        { "name": "Xor", "size": 1101 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "scale",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105 },
                        { "name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316 },
                        { "name": "LogScale", "size": 3151 },
                        { "name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770 },
                        { "name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435 },
                        { "name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839 },
                        { "name": "RootScale", "size": 1756 },
                        { "name": "Scale", "size": 4268 },
                        { "name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821 },
                        { "name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "util",
                    "children": [
                        { "name": "Arrays", "size": 8258 },
                        { "name": "Colors", "size": 10001 },
                        { "name": "Dates", "size": 8217 },
                        { "name": "Displays", "size": 12555 },
                        { "name": "Filter", "size": 2324 },
                        { "name": "Geometry", "size": 10993 },
                        {
                            "name": "heap",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354 },
                                { "name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335 },
                        { "name": "IPredicate", "size": 383 },
                        { "name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874 },
                        {
                            "name": "math",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165 },
                                { "name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815 },
                                { "name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "Maths", "size": 17705 },
                        { "name": "Orientation", "size": 1486 },
                        {
                            "name": "palette",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367 },
                                { "name": "Palette", "size": 1229 },
                                { "name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059 },
                                { "name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "Property", "size": 5559 },
                        { "name": "Shapes", "size": 19118 },
                        { "name": "Sort", "size": 6887 },
                        { "name": "Stats", "size": 6557 },
                        { "name": "Strings", "size": 22026 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "vis",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "axis",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "Axes", "size": 1302 },
                                { "name": "Axis", "size": 24593 },
                                { "name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652 },
                                { "name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636 },
                                { "name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "controls",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138 },
                                { "name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824 },
                                { "name": "Control", "size": 1353 },
                                { "name": "ControlList", "size": 4665 },
                                { "name": "DragControl", "size": 2649 },
                                { "name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832 },
                                { "name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896 },
                                { "name": "IControl", "size": 763 },
                                { "name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222 },
                                { "name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862 },
                                { "name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "data",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "Data", "size": 20544 },
                                { "name": "DataList", "size": 19788 },
                                { "name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349 },
                                { "name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301 },
                                { "name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382 },
                                {
                                    "name": "render",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "ArrowType", "size": 698 },
                                        { "name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569 },
                                        { "name": "IRenderer", "size": 353 },
                                        { "name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                { "name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275 },
                                { "name": "Tree", "size": 7147 },
                                { "name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "events",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313 },
                                { "name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880 },
                                { "name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701 },
                                { "name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "legend",
                            "children": [
                                { "name": "Legend", "size": 20859 },
                                { "name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614 },
                                { "name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530 }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "operator",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "distortion",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461 },
                                        { "name": "Distortion", "size": 6314 },
                                        { "name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "encoder",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179 },
                                        { "name": "Encoder", "size": 4060 },
                                        { "name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138 },
                                        { "name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690 },
                                        { "name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "filter",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219 },
                                        { "name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165 },
                                        { "name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                { "name": "IOperator", "size": 1286 },
                                {
                                    "name": "label",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "Labeler", "size": 9956 },
                                        { "name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899 },
                                        { "name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "layout",
                                    "children": [
                                        { "name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725 },
                                        { "name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727 },
                                        { "name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317 },
                                        { "name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003 },
                                        { "name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853 },
                                        { "name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411 },
                                        { "name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864 },
                                        { "name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174 },
                                        { "name": "Layout", "size": 7881 },
                                        { "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870 },
                                        { "name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728 },
                                        { "name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348 },
                                        { "name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870 },
                                        { "name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121 },
                                        { "name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191 }
                                    ]
                                },
                                { "name": "Operator", "size": 2490 },
                                { "name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248 },
                                { "name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190 },
                                { "name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581 },
                                { "name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023 }
                            ]
                        },
                        { "name": "Visualization", "size": 16540 }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

        function update(source) {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Update the nodes…
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on("click", toggle);

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    if (d.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    } else if (d._children) {
                        return "lightsteelblue";
                    } else {
                        return "#fff";
                    }
                })
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    if (d.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    }
                });

            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                })
                .remove();

            nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6);

            nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Update the links…
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal)
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    if (d.target.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136";
                    }
                });

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                })
                .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```